# Is there an alternative to Windows-Down to minimize?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I remember with Windows XP, minimize used to be like alt m - n or something.

In Windows 7, it is Windows - Down.

The problem with that though is that you have to use both hands (the Window button is too far away from the directional buttons), which is kind of annoying because generally, one of my hands is on the mouse.

Is there any other keyboard to minimize a window besides Windows - Down in Windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old one you're looking for (which still works) is `Alt`+`Space`, `n`.

For completeness's sake you can also minimize all with `Win`+`M`.

Comment: I also like Alt-Space-E-P in the console to paste, instead of reaching for the mouse.  Totally unrelated to the OP's question, but hey :)

Comment: Yep - another one (more related) is `Alt+Space, m` (then use arrow keys to move), for when windows are off-screen and can't be dragged.

Answer (score 3):

While not a keyboard shortcut, you can also just shake a window with the mouse to minimize all other windows in Windows 7

Comment: Huh? Please elaborate or cite.

Comment: You could just try it? It's a new feature in the Windows 7 Aero interface. It doesn't really help the OPs question though

Comment: that's pretty weird!

Answer (score 0):

The full list can be found at
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

(For other versions of Windows, http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/keyboard.aspx )

On Explorer, `F11` maximizes or minimizes the active window; but this may not work on other programs.

An alternative to `Win+M` that Mark proposed is `Win+D` to display the desktop, which effectively minimizes all the windows and is easier to type with one hand.