# What is a mouse-only way to minimize all the windows except the active one?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I've been using Windows since the version 3-something and showing the desktop by <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> is an old trick.

How do you minimize all the windows except the active one using only the mouse?

Comment: 99.9% of the time, I do this by accident.  I struggle to even *imagine* what a legitimate use case would be...

Comment: Trying the *hold & shake* since morning. Not working. The co-workers who can overlook at my monitor must thing I've gone crazy.

Comment: @sapi True, it's not very useful. Maybe except when in a meeting when you want to entertain while staling for time and you tell the audience you'll *shake down* your screen. Cool doesn't need to be useful, hehe. You're right.

Comment: @sapi If you still have the active window held with your mouse then you can just shake again to bring them back up. Although it seems like you be 300% more spastic when shaking.

Comment: @KharoBangdo I think you have Windows Aero turned off.

Comment: Do this accidentally on a slow computer with many windows open, and you will instantly learn to hate it.

Comment: This question is *far* too close to (if not outright in) the "every answer is equally valid: 'What’s your favorite ______?' " category specifically forbidden in [the help](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/comment-re-the-real-questions-have-answers-close-reason/3144?noredirect=1#comment7121_3144). "Coolest" is too subjective, as evident by the fact the keyboard shortcut is beating out the answer you were looking for. This could be reworded into something like, "Is there a mouse based way to minimize all windows except the active one?" and become a useful question.

Comment: Basically this is all these, but in a roundabout way that nobody would search for unless they already know what they http://superuser.com/questions/353215/when-i-wave-with-a-window-all-other-windows-minimize-to-the-taskbar-why/ http://superuser.com/questions/256091/is-there-an-alternative-to-windows-down-to-minimize/ http://superuser.com/questions/729247/how-to-hide-all-windows-except-the-one-that-im-using/770385#770385

Comment: @jpmc26 You're not wrong. I'd still claim that the shortcut-answer is way too mainstream to be called cool, as it doesn't defect from the usual approach (that is good, don't get me wrong - I **love** shortcuts). But it's still a matter of opinion, as someone pointed out. Also, I wasn't looking for any answer. I answered myself because I discovered a new feature (new to me at least) and wished to share it with others. The answer you're referring to, although technically correct, hijacked my intention a bit.

Comment: @random I wouldn't find them, probably. Also, one of them isn't even about Windows but Gnome (even if one of the replies talks about Windows).

Comment: @jpmc26 Also, I just re-read the question and, actually, I **do** define what's meant by *cool*. Nevertheless, you're making a valid point so I edited the question to obey the rules more obviously.

Comment: It's not a hidden feature, it was in commercials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CuVmAukssM http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/shake

Comment: @random I didn't say it's a hidden feature. I just haven't ever seen it before. None of the people I've shown it too neither. So either I need to keep myself more up to date or you need to browse youTube less.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten My point was that the question was in a form explicitly discouraged by StackExchange, and it was rightly closed as a result. I've suggested an edit that goes in line with your change to the title and will bring it back on topic. I have removed the reference to already knowing the answer, as well. This sort of content not relevant to the question itself is also discouraged/prohibited. StackExchange aims to be a high quality repository of information, not a forum. (Posting so you can self answer for the purpose of spreading knowledge is fine, by the way.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The cool way is called [Aero Shake](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd327594(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Use the mouse like you would move a Window, but shake it (move left and to right very fast).

Comment: Hey, how come you get +1 and not me?! I want some too! Seriously though - it's a obscure but very cool feature.

Comment: someone gave it to you. Next time, use the checkbox when creating a question, that you want to self answer your question, so that we no longer post the same answer the same time

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Please don't beg for reputation.  The only way to receive reputation is to post good answers and questions.

Comment: @KonradViltersten they think highly of imaginary points here. I don't bother trying to help with this site unless I actually need something because they are really not *people*-people. +1'd you anyway because I didn't know of this feature and *appreciate* the little bit of effort you gave in posting it here.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I always thought checking that box was some kind of "self-awareness" check.  Does that do something to the question to alert readers to wait for the OP's answer, or lock it until the OP has written the answer?

Comment: Only available on Windows 7 and up.

Comment: @Ramhound You missed the sarcasm. It was meant as a joke.   :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Huh? I've never seen that checkbox... Good feature, though. Using SE for three years - still learning new stuff. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @KonradViltersten - We are a serious website.  Why would I expect people to be sarcastic here?

Comment: @Ramhound I quite easily saw the joke in it. Serious sites can have fun too, you know!

Comment: @fixer1234 when you select the checkbox, the question is not published until you wrote your own answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Being a serious site doesn't exclude the possibility for humoristic contribution as long as it **contributes** to the content, which, as you can see on the other repliers' comments, I mine did. Sorry you misinterpreted but, frankly, this pathetic way to request +1 (if id' me intended) **should** make you raise an eyebrow and beg to think again if you've got it right. Have faith in people.   :)

Comment: What would happen if I shake the window up&down?

Comment: @RogUE Awesome! I know you're just playing goofy but, in fact, I got a different behavior. The non-focused windows got minimized **but** there's no shake-back if you go up&down, apparently. So we just discovered a new feature - non-restorable-unfocused-windows-shake-off!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Unfortunately, I cant test it because I am running Win basic theme.

Answer (score 79):

The keyboard combo <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> minimizes all windows except for the active one.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for sharing, I knew about the Aero Shake mentioned in the other answers, but as someone who tries to use the mouse as little as possible this is so much better.

Comment: @Windos I'm a keyboard shortcut prone too. However, this was a cool nice thingy - I've never heard about this shaky feature before. Pressing WIn+Home isn't nearly as cool. However, it's far more efficient and pro-like.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten for me, anything that is efficient and pro-like is cool

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me :(

Comment: Doesn't work for me, maybe because I'm using a French "AZERTY" keyboard layout (though I still have a home key)..

Comment: @AndréDaniel, Win + maison? =)

Comment: @Ooker Good point. However, see the comment about shaking up&down. It actually seems to be different in behavior. (Not that it's ever useful in reality, of course, but still worth mentioning.)

Comment: @ps2goat Fenêtre!

Comment: @MrLister, I assumed that the Windows key would still retain its brand name.

Comment: @ps2goat actually our "home" key is called "début" which means "beginning".

Comment: On my standard US keyboard, Windows+M and Windows+D both minimize all windows, these might have more graceful conversions to French AZERTY.

Answer (score 7):

The coolest way to minimize all the windows except the one that's active is to literally shake the window. Yes, as in:

1. click and hold on the frame of the window
2. move repetitively and  quickly to the left and right

Tada! (Credit goes to [9Gag](http://9gag.com/gag/abymwz9#comment) for this.)

Comment: That's Aero Shake.

Comment: This is actually the annoying way.  If I've had too much coffee or can't decide whether I'm going to throw the window to the left or right monitor (and thus moving the window left and right a little bit), Windows thinks I'm doing the shake, then I have to shake again to get my windows back up.

Comment: @ps2goat True... Didn't think of that. But if you keep on shaking (which should be easy, since you're having too much coffee), the windows are actually shaken back in place.   :)

Comment: Unfortunately, stupid applications like Chrome have left us little or no titlebar. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suggest you use a less stupid application such as FF. It lets you have enough of graspable area to do the trick.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Here's [Windows Explorer compared to Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gNnGn.png). The draggable area isn't that much smaller, especially if you don't have many tabs open.

Comment: @gronostaj: On Windows 7 with Aero theme you don't get that titlebar space in Chrome _at all_. The top of the tab bar is the top of the window.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit only when it's maximized. But in that case there's no point in shaking it, just click it and it will take entire screen.

Comment: @gronostaj: I think you're rather missing the point! :)

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on [user1016274's answer](http://superuser.com/a/909345/401839) a bit, I used AutoHotKey (from [AHKScript.org](http://ahkscript.org)).  So this does use third party sofware, but it seems you've been willing to try such solutions.  I put this in the script file:

```
XButton1::
    Send #{Home}
return
```

Now my 4th mouse button sends Windows+Home.  I tested this and confirmed that this does accomplish the goal that your question asked for.

If your mouse doesn't have 4 buttons, you could specify `MButton` (instead of `XButton1`) for the "Middle" (third) button.  Hopefully in today's day and age you have at least 3 buttons (possibly including pressing down on the scroll wheel) if you're using a peripheral device (rather than a built-in track pad).

If you have a spare button on your mouse, this approach might be a far simpler way (compared to trying to shake your mouse in a certain direction) to initiate your requested action, using just your mouse, as your question asked.